# Two database in single SELECT Statement

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select everything from two database: `database1` and `database2`. Both database **row** `id` is equal to `$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']`. How do i write that `sql` statement for query?

Comment: What are the names of the tables in the two respective databases?  If you really just want to select everything from two tables in the two databases, we don't need to know what the columns are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are on the same server you can just use the database.table notation:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM database1.table AS t1 WHERE t1.id = $id
UNION
SELECT t2.* FROM database2.table AS t2 WHERE t2.id = $id
```

off the top of my head